# Android how to set the transparency of shadow

Tags: android, android-elevation

I have a RelativeLayout which is on a picture. What I want to show is we can see the picture beneath the layout just through the shadow. Of course, the picture is much larger than the layout. Maybe elevation can not do this. In other words, how can I show a translucent shadow?

Comment: Put another view over your RelativeLayout (+ image) and set some semitransparent color as a background.

Comment: try  this  android:alpha="7"

Comment: What I mean is that the RelativeLayout has a shadow by setting the attribute elevation, while I want to make the shadow semitransparent. Then I can see the picture beneath the layout. Thank you all the same.